# how to Reference some model in a db.ListProperty on google-app-engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, listproperty

this is my model:

```
class Geo(db.Model):
    entry = db.ListProperty(db.Key)

geo=Geo()
geo.entry.append(otherModel.key())
```

and the html is :

```
{% for i in geo.entry %}
        <p><a href="{{ i.link }}">{{ i.title }}</a></p>
{% endfor%}
```

but it show nothing,

i think maybe should :

```
class Geo(db.Model):
    entry = db.ListProperty(db.Model)
geo=Geo()
geo.entry.append(otherModel)
```

but it show :

```
ValueError: Item type Model is not acceptable
```

so , how to make the html shows the right thing.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use that template (or the like) to show the model directly, but you can easily prepare a context with a list of models by simply calling `db.get` on the list of keys -- e.g., have `{'entries': db.get(listofkeys), ...` at the start of your context dictionary, and `for i in entries` in the template.